# Assign Instance name at runtime

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have class `Student` , I want to create multiple instance of class `Student` and want to assign instance name as S1,S2,S3..etc(1,2,3 will be id of student , so instance name will be as S+StudentID) at runtime. How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is this "instance name" you are talking about?

Comment: its reference variables name

Comment: If you would be able to create those variables at runtime, how would you access them?

Comment: @nirav: are you trying to write code at runtime? Please give example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Need something lik....for (int ID = 0; ID < 5; ID++) {
                Student s + ID = new Student();
            }

Comment: Why would you need that? (and no, it's not possible to do that in either C# or VB)

Comment: It's actually surprising to me that ppl who quite advance about C# don't really understand when such questions is asked what it is about  - its not about naming the object/instance since its imposable, its always about naming of the bucket/variable of memory that will hold/point to the object at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create reference variables during program execution but you can save object references into `List(Of Student)` or `Dictionary(Of String, Student)` collection.

```
 Dim stdList As New List(Of Student)
 stdList.Add(New Student())
```

Or

```
Dim stdMap As New Dictionary(Of String, Student)
stdMap.Add("s1", New Student())
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is have a variable in your Student class which gives a unique name for them. As AVD said, you'd still have to store them in either List or Dictionary, but this way you could use linq or select queries to find them by your given name, as long as you set the variable.

Student class;

```
studentName {get;set;}
```

Place where you create;

```
List<Student> mListStudent = new List<Student>()

For(int i = 0; i >= HoweverManyYouWantToCreate; i++)
 {
 //declare student variables
 Student student = new Student();
 studentName = i+studentID;
 mListStudent.Add(Student);
}
```

Then with something like LINQ you could get it with;

```
var selectedStudent = (from students in mListStudents
                           where students.studentName == "searchParam"
                           select students).Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its really unclear what you want, but here is a simple example how to generate the instance names:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     int id = i;
     string instanceName = String.Format("S{0}", id);
     Student s = new Student(instanceName);
     students.Add(s);
}
```